# Wrapping fused getter-setter functions

Tags: d3.js, js-of-ocaml

I'm having trouble wrapping a subset of [d3-force](https://github.com/d3/d3-force) using jooc. The library does not use object properties and instead implements fused getter-setter functions, e.g.

```
simulation.force("x", d3.forceX())  // setter
simulation.force("x")               // getter
```

I'd like to find a way to emulate the same kind of polymorphism in OCaml. Here's what I currently have

```
module Force = struct
  class type force = object
    (* not important *)
  end

  let x (): force Js.t = Js.Unsafe.meth_call __d3 "forceX" [||]

  class type simulation = object
    method force : string -> #force Js.t -> unit Js.meth
  end

  let simulation nodes: simulation Js.t =
    Js.Unsafe.(meth_call __d3 "forceSimulation" [|inject nodes|])
end
```

And here's what I'm after

```
let s = Force.simulation nodes in begin
  s##force "x" (Force.x ())
  s##force "x"  (* wishful thinking *)
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class type simulation = object
  method force_set : Js.js_string Js.t -> #force Js.t -> unit Js.meth
  method force : Js.js_string Js.t -> #force Js.t Js.meth
end
```

- JavaScript strings are not compatible with ocaml ones. use `Js.js_string Js.t`.
- `force` and `force_set` will both bind to `force`. Have a look at http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.8.1/manual/library "Method name and underscore"